# Creating and writing contents is not working in Excel using C#

Tags: c#, export-to-excel

I am trying to write into excel using below code snippet. But i am getting exception as in the sreenshot attached.

```html
try
            {
                xlApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
                xlApp.Visible = false;
                workbook = xlApp.Workbooks.Add(1);
                worksheet = (Excel.Worksheet)workbook.Sheets[1];
                workbook.SaveAs(name);
                worksheet.Cells[count, "A"] = "Name";
                worksheet.Cells[count, "B"] = "Reports_to";
                worksheet.Cells[count, "C"] = "Title";
                worksheet.Cells[count, "D"] = "Department";
                count++;
            }
            catch (System.Exception exp)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Excel Exception : " + exp.GetBaseException());
            }
```

I couldn't add screenshot as i dont have 10 reputation. My exception is as metioned below.

```html
System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x800A03EC): Exception from HRESULT: 0x800A03EC
   
at Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbooks.Add(Object Template)
   
at ReporterObj.FormExporter.InitializeExcel(String name) in d:\DJ\C# Pr

A first chance exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in ReporterObj.exe ojects\ReporterImpExp\ReporterObj\Form1.cs:line 69
```

Appropriate suggesstion is appreciated.

Thank You.

Comment: Something is null. Indexes are zero based, try `workbook.Sheets[0]`

Answer (score 0):

i get this error only in chrome but not in IE after deployment on IIS. I have narrowed this down to authentication in IIS. If you disable forms authentication this error occurs otherwise works fine.